# Basic classifier for numeric dataset

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of training data and I need to build a classifier with it. There are just two classes of elements, and the values of the attributes are all integer, like:

$$
\ [V_{11}, V_{12}, \ldots, V_{1N}] \in C_1 \\ 
\ [V_{21}, V_{22}, \ldots, V_{2N}] \in C_2 \\ 
\vdots \\
\ [V_{M1}, V_{M2}, \ldots, V_{MN}] \in C_M \\ 
\\
\ C_i \in [Class\_1, Class\_2]
$$

What kind of classifier should I use? I've been reading about Bayes classifiers but I'm not really sure if it would fit in here.

Comment: I don't get why the LaTeX code does not get rendered, but anyway...

Comment: Try replacing "\\" with "\\\". Char escaping problems maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used a Perceptron. The problem was actually pretty basic and the perceptron led to a stable state in just two training iterations.